# what does 0x0a mean in DB definition of string in asm

Tags: assembly, ascii, nasm

I write this code in assembly:

```
section .data
  message DB "Hello", 0x0a
```

what does it mean "0x0a"?

Comment: 0x0a is the line feed character. Perhaps it's defining the string "Hello\n"?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734333/how-to-interpret-hexadecimal-numbers-like-0x0a

Comment: Note that `.data:` is a bug, you want `.data` without a `:` in the section name.

Answer (score 5):

It's a byte with the value "10" in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). 10 happens to be the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) for a newline character.